# Get the image taken by DJI UX

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

I didn't find the function that took the photo in the DJI UX. I'm already tried to read the code of UX and didn't find it or understand correctly. With the function, I want to work with the image and do some image editions.

Comment: You may want to look at the API documentation of the DJI Mobile SDK as well and/or at these samples: https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android/tree/master/Sample%20Code/app/src/main/java/com/dji/sdk/sample/demo/camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DJI UX SDK uses the default DJI SDK (No UX) behind it.

I recommend you to take a look into DJI SDK [Camera Application tutorial](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/android-tutorials/index.html).

To take a picture you can take using this code:

```java
// Method for taking photo
private void captureAction(){

    final Camera camera = DJISDKManager.getInstance().getProduct().getCamera();
    if (camera != null) {

        SettingsDefinitions.ShootPhotoMode photoMode = SettingsDefinitions.ShootPhotoMode.SINGLE; // Set the camera capture mode as Single mode
        camera.setShootPhotoMode(photoMode, new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onResult(DJIError djiError) {
                    if (null == djiError) {
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                camera.startShootPhoto(new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResult(DJIError djiError) {
                                        if (djiError == null) {
                                            showToast("take photo: success");
                                        } else {
                                            showToast(djiError.getDescription());
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                }
        });
    }
}
```

Retrieving the picture you just took is a little complicate task. The example code at [Media Manager Application Tutorial](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/android-tutorials/MediaManagerDemo.html) explains how to do it. What you will have to do is use MediaManager class to get the list of every image and video stored in the drone SD card, and then download the most recent one.